# Three Forms, One Submit button on the same page. Need it to submit to one line in the mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

First, the reason why I have three forms on one page is for layout purposes.  I have three input boxes going across one line and then another under it and so on.  If I place them under one form tag, I get bad looking input boxes that goes from top to bottom.  I have tried some solutions but they have not worked. Each line would put 3 three entries instead of one and some data would not show up or only one form would show up in the database.

HTML

```
<form class="form-inline"  id="Test1" method="POST"> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<label>Name: <input name="FN" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value=""> </label>  </div> </form>


<form class="form-inline"  id="Test2" method="POST"> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<label>Name: <input name="LN" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value=""> </label>  </div> </form>


<form class="form-inline"  id="Test3" method="POST"> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<label>Name: <input name="EM" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value=""> </label>  </div> </form>

<div class="form-group"><br> 
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2"> <button type="button" class="SB btn btn-default">Book Now</button> </div> 
                <script>
                  $(document).on('click','.SB',function(e) {
    formData = $('#Test1, #Test2', '#Test3').serialize();
    $.post(
        'Process.php', formData
    );
});
```

I only get the first form with this and the other two are blank but are on a single line.  All inputs are unique. I have also tried the docbyid and it would add three lines but not work correctly.  Any Help would be great.

PHP:

```
     require('DBCon.php');

$statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO Database (FN, LN, EM) VALUES( :CFN, :CLN, :CE)");

$ClientFN = $_POST['FN'];
$ClientLN = $_POST['LN'];
$ClientEmail = $_POST['EM'];

$statement->execute(array(
":CFN" => "$ClientFN",
":CLN" => "$ClientLN",
":CE" => "$ClientEmail"));

  $statement = null;
    $link = null;

 // Echo Successful attempt
  echo "<p Data added to database.</p></br></br>";       
  ?>
```

Comment: `firstFormData + secondFormData + thirdFormData` - What actual value is this producing?  You should be creating a single JSON object, not just smashing a few of them together.

Comment: I am not sure as I pulled that from someone on here but it didn't work.  I am still learning and hitting walls here.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I have decided to scrap this and I found a way to break it into one form with CSS.  I appreciate the help from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your button should call a function rather than submit the form. Submitting will only send the data from the first form.
You should really use one form and use CSS to correct any display issues, but if you were to use separate forms, the following should do what you are looking for *(make sure your closing tags are in the correct place)*:

```
<form class="form-inline"  id="Test1"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name: <input name="FN" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value=""></label>
    </div> 
</form>
<form class="form-inline"  id="Test2" method="POST"> 
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label>Name: <input name="LN" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value=""> </label>
    </div> 
</form>
<form class="form-inline"  id="Test3" method="POST"> 
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <label>Name: <input name="EM" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value=""> </label>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2"> <button type="button" class="sumbitButton btn btn-default">Book Now</button>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on('click','.sumbitButton',function(e) {
        formData = $('#Test1, #Test2', '#Test3').serialize();
        $.post(
            'Process.PHP', formData
        );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It only did the first form, I wondering if it has to do with my process.php.  It does the first name but does not fill the other inputs.  I tried to edit with my php script but it being reviewed.

Comment: You can use print_r($_POST); to confirm that the variables are being passed. Ensure that you have changed the button type to "button" so that it isn't submitting the form normally.

Comment: Your edits still have the closing divs on the wrong side of the form tag and you haven't changed the button type.

Comment: When I click on the button after making the changes, it does nothing.

Comment: I have decided to scrap this and I found a way to break it into one form with CSS.  I appreciate the help from everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="Process.PHP">

    <div class="form-inline"> 
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name: <input name="FN" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value=""></label>
        </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-inline"> 
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <label>Name: <input name="LN" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value=""> </label>
        </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="form-inline"> 
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <label>Name: <input name="EM" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value=""> </label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2"> <button type="submit" class="sumbitButton btn btn-default">Book Now</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: I have decided to scrap this and I found a way to break it into one form with CSS.  I appreciate the help from everyone.

Comment: It is not exactly what I did?